# ping -a not resolving hostnames of remote computers

Tags: cmd, command-prompt, ping, lan, hostname

After attempting to use the ping -a command with a remote ip address connected to the same LAN network, the command prompt does not show me the remote computer's hostname

What I have been entering currently is

```
ping -a 192.168.0.205
```

The output of this resolves to

```
Pinging 192.168.0.205 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.16.0.205: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.16.0.205: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.16.0.205: bytes=32 time=53ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.16.0.205: bytes=32 time=75ms TTL=64
```

Nowhere in this output does the command prompt state the hostname of the remote computer.
Is there a way to resolve the hostnames of remote computers in the command prompt?
If so what would you use to do this?

I have already tried using arp -a, netstat -a, ipconfing /all, and nbtstat -a and none of these have worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were on Linux, you could use the following command to do a reverse lookup on your DNS server:

```
host 192.168.0.205
```

or

```
nslookup 192.168.0.205
```

However, it is likely that you don't have a DNS server within your local network and therefore no computers have externally visible hostnames.

Comment: the only problem is that I am using windows

Comment: is there an alternative to "host" in windows

Comment: You could try `nslookup`

Comment: When I try nslookup, I get a response that says that the server is "UnKnown" and the address is 192.168.0.1. I also receive a response that states that UnKnown can't find 192.168.0.205 because its a "Non-existant domain"

Comment: Are you sure that machine has a DNS assigned hostname?